# Summing up Associative array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array(
    [User1] => 162
    [User2] => 15
    [User3] => 158
    [User4] => 92
    [User5] => 2
    [User6] => 3
    [User7] => 2
    [User8] => 25
    [User9] => 10
    [User10] => 6
    [User11] => 14
)
```

Above is my array of arrays.  This list is completely dynamic - the values(numbers) change, and all of the Users are not numbers, but have actual user names - they don't say User1, they say instead like TomJohnson4512 - on and on, they're all different

All I want to do, is some sort of loop to add up and display/print/echo the values.  I don't care about the user names, all I want is a sum of the values.

Any ideas?

Comment: there's already a built in [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) that does that for you, just search it

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is use `array_sum ( $array )` so assuming your array is called `$array`, do this

```
$total = array_sum ( $array );
```

Comment: `$total = array_sum ( $viewerPoints[0] );

echo '<pre>' . print_r($total) . '</pre>'; `

This is what I've put - but the output is:

981
1

the 981 is correct, what's the 1?